# Regex with linux file tar

Tags: python, regex

When i execute `ll` in console, the result that i get be like:

```
total 32
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 30720 May  2 00:05 20160501.tar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 30720 May  3 00:05 20160502.tar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 30720 May  4 00:05 20160503.tar
```

I try to use regex with python to verify the there is three file with correct name in that folder. But the problem is, file tar in linux have some color code. The log that I receive:

```
total 32
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 30720 May  2 00:05 [01;31m20160501.tar[0m
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 30720 May  3 00:05 [01;31m20160502.tar[0m
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 30720 May  4 00:05 [01;31m20160503.tar[0m
```

- Before '[' there is a special character 'ESC'

So is there any way to verify log with regex and python.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an alias ll set up which unconditionally turns on colour.  This is wrong.

To verify:

```
type ll
type ls
```

To fix:

```
unalias ll
unalias ls
```

Comment: Thank you but how could you undo this ? I mean turn on color.

Comment: See ````help alias```` and ````man ls````.  The option you need is ````--color=auto````.

Comment: @Tim.C you don't need to `unalias`, it suffices to _properly_ define your aliases.  In particular, the naked `--color` option is to be avoided in an alias definition.

Comment: Using ````--color=auto```` is almost always OK, though.   It uses colour only when stdout is a tty.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `ll` is neither a system command nor a shell builtin but it's rather an *alias*, usually defined in the file `~/.bashrc`.

It seems that in your definition of `ll` you (or your distribution) have stated the following

```
alias ll='ls -l ... --color=always .. '
```

or even

```
alias ll='ls -l ... --color ...'
```

as the option `--color` alone, with no value specified, takes `always` as default.

In my opinion, the right course of action is to modify the *alias* definition

```
alias ll='ls -l ... --color=auto ...'
```

`auto` implies that the output is *colorized* only when it is directed to a terminal, and not when it is directed into a pipe.

A possible drawback is that you'll miss the possibility of piping the colorized output into `less` but then you can define a shell function (here I'm assuming you're using a shell of Bourne ancestry)

```
lll () { ls -l ... --color=always ... $@ | less -R ; }
```